# MapboxGL.PointAnnotation not loading svg or Images in functional component

Tags: react-native, expo, mapbox-gl, mapbox-ios

My marker component is not loading local images or svg.
PointAnnotation dowsnot load images or svg
using MarkerView loads images but cannot click or attach press event

```
const Marker = ({ coordinate, image, id,svg ,onMarkerPress,data}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  const componentRef = useRef(null)
  const clickHandle = () => {
    navigate(dashboard, { page: PROSHOP, passedData: {item:data}})
    // dispatch(setSelectedCoordinates([parseInt(coordinate.longitude),parseInt(coordinate.latitude)]))
  };
  const loadHandler =()=>{
    setIsLoaded(true);
    componentRef.current.forceUpdate();
  }
  return (
    <View>
      {/* <MapboxGL.Camera zoomLevel={12} centerCoordinate={coordinate} /> */}
      <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
        id={`place-${data?.data?.vendor_id}`}
        key={`place-${data?.data?.vendor_id}`}
        coordinate={coordinate}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={clickHandle}
        >
        <View
          style={
            {
              height: 30,
              width: 80,
              // backgroundColor: "red",
              borderRadius: 50,
              borderColor: "#fff",
              borderWidth: 0,
              display:'flex',
              flexDirection:'row',
              alignContent:'center',
              alignSelf:'center'
            }
          }
        >
         {isLoaded? <Image
            onLoadEnd={loadHandler}
            style={{
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              // borderColor: "white",
              borderWidth: 0,
              // backgroundColor: "white",
              // borderRadius: 10,
            }}
            source={image}
          />:  <WithLocalSvg asset={svgFile} width={30} height={30} />}
               
               {/* <WithLocalSvg asset={svgFile} width={30} height={30} /> */}
              
          <Text style={{fontSize:Fonts.verysmall,color:Colors.black,fontWeight:Fonts.bold}}> {data?.data?.store_name} {data?.data?.patient}</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am passing local image file while using marker component but dosnot shows. image is loading in marker view but onPress or onSelected is not working in MarkerView can you look into this`